# Get the ID of a page in Parent combobox in editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, block-editor

I have a custom post type and a metabox with custom post_meta fields.

Parent dropdown field in editor's sidebar used to be a `<select>` element. I have some scripts that `onChange` trigger the hide/show of different fields in the metabox making them conditional, depending whether the page being edited is a parent or child:

```
$(document).on("change", ".editor-page-attributes__parent select", function(){
    toggleFields();
}
```

The options in the `<select>` have IDs as values so I could get Title and ID for the selected parent and dynamically show some data in the metabox for my user:

```
var dropdown = $('.editor-page-attributes__parent select');
var parentName = dropdown.find(':selected').text();
var parentId = dropdown.val();
```

Since v5.6 Wordpress has replaced that select element with a [Combo Box](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/combobox-control/). I have tried to get the same data `onChange` and only had some success using `blur`:

```
$(document).on("blur", ".editor-page-attributes__parent .components-combobox-control__input", function(){
    toggleFields();
    var parentName = dropdown.val();
})
```

I was only able to get the page title since this combobox now has an input element that's missing IDs, like this one:

```
<input id="components-form-token-input-0" type="text" class="components-combobox-control__input components-form-token-field__input" value="Page Name Here">
```

I have also tried doing an Ajax, to retrieve the ID using `get_page_by_title()` but it does not always work because pages might have the same title and editor also adds dashes and spaces in names for hierarchy levels.

How can I get the associated ID of the page selected in the Parent Combobox on change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time reading the [Editor Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/) I found the proper solution. This is how you can listen to changes and get the id of the Parent Combobox select in the WP Editor:

```
wp.data.subscribe( function () {
  var newParent = wp.data.select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('parent');
  console.log(newParent);
} );
```

`wp.data.subscribe` is called every single time a change occurs in the current state while editing posts in the editor, so the listener function is called every single time. We can avoid that with a simple variable check when there is an actual change to the field we want. [It behaves as Redux subscribe](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-data/#generic-stores) without unsubscribe and only one listener.

To also check for the current post type we are editing we can use  [getCurrentPostType](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core-editor/#getCurrentPostType):

```
wp.data.select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType();
```

This is the full code for this problem for future reference:

```
if (wp.data.select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType() == 'cpt_name') {
 const getPostParent = () => wp.data.select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('parent');

 // set initial parent
 let postParent = getPostParent();

 wp.data.subscribe(() => {

    // get current parent
    const newPostParent = getPostParent();    

    // only if parent changes
    if( postParent !== newPostParent ) {
      // Do what we want after parent changed
         toggleFields();
    }

    // update the variable
    postParent = newPostParent;

 });

}
```